# How to filter wp-json/wp/v2/users response on custom metas?

Tags: rest-api

I need to filter the WP-JSON of users on custom meta stored with user, I have tried filter[] parameter but not working, Here is a sample link of API https://themographics.com/wordpress/service-providers/wp-json/wp/v2/users

Comment: Note that filtering anything via meta is going to be super slow/expensive

Comment: alright that is not the main issue, main thing is how to filter then optimization is second step

Comment: Ok, but keep in mind it's not possible to optimise meta queries unless you refactor to use something else for storage. The optimisation step happened when you were planning it out on paper long before coding began. If you need to search for things be it users posts etc, use taxonomies, they're designed for search/filter. Meta is designed to be fast when you already know the user/post ID, their performance at search/filter is incredibly poor